# My document seems to contain a strange font - different from every other document

Tags: fonts

I've written several documents in LaTeX, but when I compile this special one I get this... strange "font" (not sure it can be called a font).

Help, what did I change? I remember having this problem in my very first days of LaTeX, but I don't remember how I solved it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a minimal example of code that presents the problem?

Comment: While trying to minimize, I solved it. For future reference, just remove

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: Normally you _want_ T1 encoding (especially if you need to hyphenate any words with accented characters) The problem is not that T1 is specified but that somewhere your font maps  are wrong, probably missing type1 versions of the fonts, hard to tell with no information.

Answer (score 10):

The picture you're showing has a simple explanation: your TeX distribution misses the Type1 version for the Computer Modern fonts in the T1 encoding (actually European Modern, but it's almost hair splitting).

You *can* remove the call

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

with the disadvantage that words containing an accented letter might not be hyphenated past the accent. This is usually not much of a problem when writing in English; the only problematic word that can be seen is Königsberg.

The real solution is to install the Type1 version; the distribution package is the one containing the CMSuper fonts. How you install it depends on the distribution.
If you like using the Computer Modern fonts, another possibility is adding

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

because the Latin Modern fonts are almost the same (with actually some improvement when certain accented letters are considered).

Answer (score 2):

Your font setting is not correct. As David wrote using `[T1]` should be the default with `pdflatex`. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
From a mathematical point of view, graph theory was born to \ldots
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]