# Why do the letters in the PDF become blurry after compiling when I add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to my LaTeX preamble?

Tags: packages, pdf, vscode

Before adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble I have in the pdf preview
[image]

After I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I get

[image]

Why? Can anyone  help me please?

Comment: you have not installed the  cmsuper collection of type1 fonts

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179988/my-document-seems-to-contain-a-strange-font-different-from-every-other-documen/180012#180012